# How to update different id as same id using same name in sql database

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have to eliminate different id and update the ids with the first id using the same product name column in SQL for example:

Actual table:

```
id     product_name
-------------------
p1     apple
p2     apple
p3     grape
p4     grape
p5     grape
```

The updated table should be like:

```
id     product_name
-------------------
p1     apple
p1     apple
p3     grape
p3     grape
p3     grape
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be done using UPDATE with correlated sub query

```
UPDATE table1 AS a SET id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM table1 AS b WHERE
b.product_name = a.product_name );
```

See [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c76a484aa1f44a2bb0387c507aee83f4). Tested with  Postgresql 10 not amazon redshift

Comment: In amazon redshift ? Did you check the link ? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c76a484aa1f44a2bb0387c507aee83f4

Comment: Instead of Postgresql can u say for sql serever

Comment: See link for for SQL Server 2017 https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=60fe2c66adb2df01987589322c3bd48c

Comment: Thanks, man. Is inserting the updated value in new column in same table is possible?

Comment: If we have id has any random character which value it will take as first value for eg ids : (12abc, abcds, teuac) for same product_name

Answer (score 0):

You could try and join a derived table that computes the target id, as follows:

```
update t
set t.id = x.id
from mytable t
inner join (
    select product_name, min(id) id from mytable group by product_name
) x on x.product_name = t.product_name
```

Comment: getting relation t does not exist in redshift

Answer (score 0):

You can try using common table expression. [common table expression in redshift](https://popsql.com/learn-sql/redshift/how-to-write-a-common-table-expression-in-redshift/)

```
;WITH CTE_productName AS
(
SELECT product_name, min(id)
FROM Product
)
UPDATE p
SET p.id = c.id
FROM Product AS p
JOIN CTE_ProductName AS c
ON p.product_name = c.product_name
```

Comment: Did you change the table name. I just mentioned product as I dont know the table name. Also, check the case of alias. I have put smallcase now

Answer (score 0):

Use group by with min to update   with the below corelated subquery

```
    Update table  t set id=(Select min(id) 
        from 
     table t where 
      product_name=t.product_name   
     group by product_name  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use case and subquery

hope this help :)

```
UPDATE table_name SET id= ( case when product_name= 'apple' then 'p1' when product_name= 'grape' then 'p3' else id END );
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
UPDATE table_name SET id= (
  case when product_name= 'apple' then 'p1' 
  when product_name= 'grape' then 'p3' 
  else id END );
```

Comment: Consider add some explanation with your answer, beside the answer it self, it will help other people much more

Comment: for 2  products it's fine then for thousands  for a different product

Comment: Sure, sorry, im quite new . will do next time

Answer (score 0):

In Redshift, I would phrase this as:

```
update actual t
    set id = tt.min_id
    from (select product_name, min(id) as min_id
          from actual t
          group by product_name
         ) tt
     where tt.product_name = t.product_name and
           tt.min_id <> t.id;
```

I assume this is a simplification of your actual problem.  Having a table with exact duplicates is usually not helpful.

Comment: t does not exists

Comment: @DarkNinja . . . `t` is a table alias for your table, which I have called `actual` in the query, because you have called it that in your question.